# How do I call a number from call log

Tags: android, call, phone-call, calllog

I need help with being able to dial the numbers from the call log. I need to make a user able to click on one of the numbers and calling that number. I think I need to make an array but I don't really know or maybe the numbers should become links?.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView call;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        call = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.call); //finds textview
        getCallDetails();
        final TextView dialers=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.call);
        dialers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse("tel://"+ dialers.getText().toString().trim())));
            }
        });

    }
    private void getCallDetails() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null,null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.NUMBER );
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.TYPE );
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append( "Call Details :");
        while ( managedCursor.moveToNext() ) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString( number );
            String callType = managedCursor.getString( type );
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString( date );
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString( duration );
            String dir = null;


            int dircode = Integer.parseInt( callType );
            switch( dircode ) {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir = "OUTGOING";
                    break;
                    //gets outcoming calls

                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir = "INCOMING";
                    break;
                    //gets incoming calls

                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir = "MISSED";
                    break;

            }
            sb.append( "\nPhone Number:--- "+phNumber +" \nCall Type:--- "+dir+" \nCall Date:--- "+callDayTime+" \nCall duration in sec :--- "+callDuration );
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");


        }
        managedCursor.close();
        call.setText(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these attributes to the `call` TextView where you show the phone numbers:

```
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:linksClickable="true"
```

and the numbers will have a link color and when you click the number you will start the dial app.

or

```
call.setText(sb);
call.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
Linkify.addLinks(call, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Comment: Isn't this a textview?

Comment: Yes it is! It looks like this.
`<TextView
        android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:linksClickable="true">
    </TextView>`

Comment: No they are not :/

Comment: instead of TextView in xml try android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Comment: I'm sorry for taking your time but I still don't get any links,

Comment: one more try, remove `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: I thought of that but it didn't help... Do you think I need to work on changing the code instead?

Comment: No, this would be enough because I use it in my app and works fine. I'm thinking that the format of the number is not recognized as phone number

Comment: I'm trying to fix it through PhoneNumberUtils but it stil won't work even though the numbers are displayed like "222- 533-8556"

Comment: can you try `managedCursor.getString( number ).replaceAll("-","");` so that there is only a 10 digit number?

Comment: I noticed that some of my phone numbers are 4 digits, maybe that is what causes the problem? With the managedcursor I now only see the numbers as ”234567”

Comment: From what I see in my app, only 10 digit numbers are recognized and it does not matter if they have `-` between the digits but not spaces